# Webservices invocation exception -- where am I going wrong I have this class in classpath

Tags: java, web-services

This is a webservice. This service is properly working fine through java application but when I make this as jar and run from the web project I am getting this exception "SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" and at the end Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/oracle/ccpayment

Comment: Show us the java class whose line throws that exception. Also show the complete stack trace.

Comment: Whatever jar contains the com/oracle/ccpayment class - is it either in the app server's startup classpath OR in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your web app war file?

Comment: I have added in the lib folder and its working fine. Thanks a ton!